# Non editable internal reference string for excel file

Tags: excel, ms-office

We have a web application that allows users to generate excel reports.

We would to have a way to set reference value to one of the properties of the excel file so that we can identify if the excel report belonged to our system

Most of the properties like "Title","Subject" etc are editable by a user by right clicking on the excel file > properties > details

Is there a property that is non editable by a user?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is there a property non-editable by a user?

No.

But concerning "identify if the excel report belonged to our system", you may use some tricks. The easiest (for implementation) I can think of are:

- Save the file as `*.xlsb`, insert a module in VBA and write something in the module. Then save the VBA with a password;
- Add a very hidden worksheet and write something on it. Or simply rename the very hidden worksheet somehow, which would tell you that this is your worksheet;
- Add a specific conditional formatting and do not implement it anywhere. Thus, every worksheet, that contains the conditional format would be yours;

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @vityata, will try out the "very hidden worksheet" approach and let you know